# requirejs execute require module again

Tags: requirejs

f.e. i have:

```
require( ['module1'], function( module1_callback){
//callback_1 after code is loaded
} );
```

and module1.js

```
define( ['module2'], function(module2_callback)
{
    //function_1 to perform something
    return 'something';
});
```

i need module1 on demand but i need to run function_1 everytime i requre that module,
in this case function_1 in module1 is executed only on first load but i need that routine every time i require module1. only return callback is executed

Answer (score 2):

This is not the way requirejs works. But you can return a function that will perform something and then return something:

```
define( ['module2'], function(module2_callback) {
  return function() { 
    //to perform something
    return 'something';
  }
});
```

and in your base module:

```
require( ['module1'], function( module1_callback){
   var something = module1_callback();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

retrieving functions introduces more complexity and it is not working in some cases with backbone plugins and circular dependencies especialy on large 1page app where some parts of the page needs to be reinitialized from scratch,
i endup using magic modules

https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Differences-between-the-simplified-CommonJS-wrapper-and-standard-AMD-define#wiki-magic

and `undef`

```
define( ['module2', 'module'], function(module2_callback) {
     //push module id into global array 
     window.undefArr.push(module);
    //all code here will be executed on every require
});
```

and

```
//before require undef modules
//here you can control which modules undef which to leave in memory
//based on module properties like path, name, status etc.
_.each( window.undefArr, function(mod){
   requirejs.undef(mod.id);
});
//init undefArr
undefArr = [];
require( ['module1']);
```

Comment: Does that mean that every undefined module needs to be loaded again and how does this work with compiled modules?

Comment: context wont be loaded again, it will be taken from cache but only file context, if your module returning compiled stuff it will be recompiled, basiccaly it will do eval on that module again

Comment: You approach looks a bit overcomplicated. Wouldn't it be easier to just add an reset functionality to your module itself. Or even better have an getter in in your module that gives you a new instance.

Comment: my apps each section is using 1 file for all backbone collections and 1 file per each view for section, i could actually go 1 collection/1 module per file but it is huge change and modules and collections usualy are 5 lines length, so doing `undef` really helps